# What is the purpose of using cbind in r for multivariate regression?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to see if A1_IS (internalised stigma) predicts A1_CSI (couple satisfaction at time1) and A2_CSI(couple satisfaction at time 2). So i think this is multivariate regression right?
My R code:

```r
mod0 <- lm(cbind(A1_CSI, A2_CSI) ~ A1_IS, data = newdata) 
summary(mod0)
```

This gives me a non-sig result, p >0.05.

However, when i run each model separately, this gives me a significant result.

```r
mod0 <- lm(A1_CSI ~ A1_IS, data = newdata)
```

Can anyone help me explain why this is the case? What is the difference of running each model separately and running 2 models at the same time using `cbind` function?

Comment: (+1) Welcome to CV.  I'm sorry about the downvote: I suspect the strong emphasis on `R`, including framing your problem as an `R` question, may have caused some readers not to recognize the fundamental statistical issue here.  If you're comfortable restating your question using English and mathematics, doing so might bring more attention from knowledgeable readers.

Comment: Maybe you could also include some (relevant parts of) output from the models?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your situation.  The first call to `lm` carries out and reports on the two separate univariate regressions, so there is no difference.  Please give an example of the behavior you report.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first code models your dependent variables with single predictor which also means that cbind used brings together the two dependent variables. Which is right for multivariate regression. However your second code suggests bivariable regression thats a single dependent variable and a predictor. Sig pvalue there shows the the predictor  predicts only the dependent variable or independently.

Comment: yeah but i dont understand why the results from first code show IS doest predict A1_CSI, but if i run 2 regressions separeately, it shows IS predicts A1_CSI